# jQuery i have invoice calculation part it not working properly

Tags: jquery, math

I'm trying implementing  a discount value getting in my form.
im entering
**my form if i entered value it added +2 value**

```
|QTY    GST(TAX)    DISC    RATE  AMOUNT
| 1         18%      10%    100$   108$| // its was wrong Amount Answer
```

**right answer 106.20$**

but i am getting wrong how to slow this help me

```js
$('tbody').delegate('.quantity,.price,.gst,.dsc', 'keyup', function() {
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  var quantity = tr.find('.quantity').val();
  var price = tr.find('.price').val();
  var gst = tr.find('.gst').val();
  var dcs = tr.find('.dcs').val();
  var totalamountgst = (quantity * price * gst) / 100;
  var totalamountdcs = (quantity * price * dcs) / 100;
  var totalamounts = (quantity * price + totalamountgst);
  var totalamount = (totalamounts - totalamountdcs);


  tr.find('.totalamount').val(totalamount);
  total();
});

function total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.totalamount').each(function(i, e) {
    var totalamount = $(this).val() - 0;
    total += totalamount;
  });
  $('.total').val(total + ".00");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control quantity" name="qty[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="QTY" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control gst " name="gst_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="GST" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control dcs " name="dcs_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="DCS" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="number" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control price" name="purchase_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="RATE" value="" required pattern="" numbers="" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalamount" name="" id="validationServer01" placeholder="AMOUNT" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please start by properly explaining what your formula is actually supposed to be. (We _could_ possible determine that from looking at it, but we should not _have to_.)

Comment: @CBroe open this link https://www.omnicalculator.com/finance/discount add same values i mention after run my code enter same value that time you will get difference of amount

Comment: Your question needs to be self-contained, and not rely on external resources for clarity. So please _explain_ what the formula is supposed to be here, instead of referring us elsewhere.

Comment: @CBroe im doing calculation part im adding 18% of tax and 10% discount, on rate100$, but it giving total amount 108$, its wrong total amount . right answer 106.20$ , problem is  its not giving proper value

Comment: @CBroe i want to fix that total amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the discounts have to be applied before calculating the tax, so:

```js
$('tbody').delegate('.quantity,.price,.gst,.dsc', 'keyup', function() {
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  var quantity = tr.find('.quantity').val();
  var price = tr.find('.price').val();
  var gst = tr.find('.gst').val();
  var dcs = tr.find('.dcs').val();
  var totalprice = quantity * price;
  var totaldiscount = (totalprice * dcs) / 100;
  var totalvatable = totalprice - totaldiscount;
  var totalvat = (totalvatable * gst) / 100;
  var totalamount = totalvatable + totalvat;


  tr.find('.totalamount').val(totalamount);
  total();
});

function total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.totalamount').each(function(i, e) {
    var totalamount = $(this).val() - 0;
    total += totalamount;
  });
  $('.total').val(total + ".00");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control quantity" name="qty[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="QTY" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control gst " name="gst_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="GST" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control dcs " name="dcs_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="DCS" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="number" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control price" name="purchase_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="RATE" value="" required pattern="" numbers="" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalamount" name="" id="validationServer01" placeholder="AMOUNT" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, is there possible show entire discount amount as well total filled rows count ,like showing total amount

Answer (score 1):

You had first to subtract the dcs and on this add the gst. It's better to use `parseInt` on the values.

```js
$('tbody').delegate('.quantity,.price,.gst,.dsc', 'keyup', function() {
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  var quantity = parseFloat(tr.find('.quantity').val());
  var price = parseFloat(tr.find('.price').val());
  var gst = parseFloat(tr.find('.gst').val());
  var dcs = parseFloat(tr.find('.dcs').val());
  var totalamount = quantity*price*(100-dcs)/100*(100+gst)/100;

  tr.find('.totalamount').val(totalamount);
  total();
});

function total() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.totalamount').each(function(i, e) {
    var totalamount = $(this).val() - 0;
    total += totalamount;
  });
  $('.total').val(total + ".00");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control quantity" name="qty[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="QTY" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control gst " name="gst_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="GST" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control dcs " name="dcs_amount[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="DCS" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="number" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control price" name="purchase_rate[]" id="validationServer01" placeholder="RATE" value="" required pattern="" numbers="" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" class="text-danger  input-lg form-control totalamount" name="" id="validationServer01" placeholder="AMOUNT" value="" required pattern="[1-2-3-4-3-5-6-7-8-9-10-12]+" numbers="onlynumbers" disabled></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you, is there possible show entire discount amount as well total filled rows count ,like showing total amount

Comment: thank you, is there possible show entire discount amount as well total filled rows count ,like showing total amount